# How can I add a picked image into core data

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I am a new guys on swift 3 (xcode) and I am working on a project.

I am building a data base with core data, and inserting data in there.

Now in this project a user can choose a picture in his device and than I should save it into core data.

I have this so far:

```
   func addUser() {

    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


    let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Users", into: context)


    if (firstName.text == "" && lastName.text == "" && contact.text == "" && email.text == "") {    //if we have a user profile delete it
        deleteUser()

    } else {    //add a new user profile

    newUser.setValue(firstName.text, forKey: "firstName")
    newUser.setValue(lastName.text, forKey: "lastName")
    newUser.setValue(contact.text, forKey: "contact")
    newUser.setValue(email.text, forKey: "email")


    let imgUrl = UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL as! NSURL

    print(imgUrl) //should print selected photo however not doing it


        //Saving image
    let img = UIImage(named: "imgUrl")

    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!, 1)

    newUser.setValue(imgData, forKey: "photo")




    print ("Data added in Users")

    }

    do {

        try context.save()

    } catch {

    }



}
```

I am making the user choose a photo with a UIImagePickerController:

```
 @IBAction func addPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary 

    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(image, animated: true)
    {


    }

}

//image adding - galery
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        imageView.image = image

    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now, something is missing I know. How can I make the user save his picked image into core data like this?

Should I get the url of choosed image? I tried but couldnt :( Or is there a better solution?

Comment: you should __not__ add a blob to any database directly (for preventing performance issues), maybe you should store the binary file somewhere in the file system (e.g. either Library or Documents folder) and keep a reference (e.g. filename) in your database only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting image from `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL as! NSURL`. You can get the image from `imageView`. Then you can convert that image into `NSData` to store in core data.

```
let img = imageView.image

let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!, 1)
```

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Tried. NOw I get an error in let imgData=  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!, 1).    "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Check img reference is having image or not.

Comment: We have to get the image from imagePicker. So you can create one global variable and assign image to that variable in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method. Use the global variable to get the image for" let img = globalVariable". Declare the globalVariable as UIImage